# Is more than one method call possible at the onclick of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I was wondering if i can call two functions at the onclick of a button? Basically what i have is a form which submit button calls a function which saves the field values into localstorage. What i want to do is when the user clicks the save button, the data will be INSERTED into a MSYQL database. How can i do that? As with that button i am calling save() function which saves them at the localstorage. Can more than one function be called on one button onclick? Below is my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>


<title>Localstorage Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function save(){

            var fieldvalue = document.getElementById('textfield1').value;
            var fieldvalue1 = document.getElementById('textfield2').value;
            var fieldvalue2 = document.getElementById('textfield3').value;

            localStorage.setItem('text',fieldvalue);
            localStorage.setItem('text1',fieldvalue1);
            localStorage.setItem('text2',fieldvalue2);
        }

        function load(){
            var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('text');
            var storedValue1 = localStorage.getItem('text1');
            var storedValue2 = localStorage.getItem('text2');

            if(storedValue){
                document.getElementById('textfield1').value = storedValue;
            }

            if(storedValue1){
                document.getElementById('textfield2').value = storedValue1;
            }

            if(storedValue2){
                document.getElementById('textfield3').value = storedValue2;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">      
        <input type="text" id="textfield1" />
        <input type="text" id="textfield2" />
        <input type="text" id="textfield3" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="save()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since the functionality is the same (load from localStorage / db and save to localStorage and db) you can extend your existing functions. To access the database you will need to use Ajax and a server-side language (php, perl, python, .net).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to call more than one function in `onclick` event:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="save(); alert('hello!');">
```